# How to get parent name in php mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table :

```
brand(id, parent_id, name)
       1      0      Apple 
       2      1      Macbook Air
       3      1      Iphone 4S
imgae(id, brand_id, image)
       1      2      mac.png
       2      3      iphone.png
```

And mysql:

```sql
SELECT br.name, img.image FROM image as img
LEFT JOIN brand AS br ON br.parent_id = img.brand_id
```

And result is:

```
Macbook Air |   mac.png
Iphone 4S   |   iphone.png
```

How to get parent name from table brand

```
Macbook Air |   mac.png     | Apple
Iphone 4S   |   iphone.png  | Apple
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT brand.id, brand.name, brandName.name as parentName, images.image FROM brand 
INNER JOIN brand as brandName ON brand.parent_id=brandName.id 
LEFT JOIN images ON brand.id=images.brand_id
```

### i changed LEFT JOIN to INNER JOIN

please check again.

Answer (score 2):

I try not to use a self referencing table as you get problems like this one.  Take another look at your database/table design.

```
Manufacture(
 ID
,Name)

Image(
 ID
,Blob
,URL)

Product(
 ID
,ImageID
,ManID
,Name
,Description
)
```

SQL

```
Select 
     M.Name as Brand
    ,P.Name as Product
    ,I.URL as ImageURL
FROM 
    Product AS P
JOIN Manufacture AS M ON
    P.ManID = M.ID
LEFT JOIN Image AS I ON
    P.ImageID = I.ID`
```

hope that helps.

**PS.** I would also recommend breaking your tables up from a management point of view. Say you wish to remove all Apple products, you can remove Apple from Manufacture table (by setting a column `IsActive` to `0`, and updating you SQL to select only rows `WHERE M.IsActive = 1` ) removing Apple and all products linked via ManID.